# How can I provide an http return code from HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a web app, with a doGet() function.

If there is something wrong in the parameters list, I would like to return an HTTP error. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using servlets for this. If you are using servlets, the syntax for doGet is

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

In your method you can check your parameters in HttpServletRequest from

```
req.getParamenter("parameterName")
```

and if the required parameter is not found you can set the value or error response in your response from

```
res.sendError(ERROR_CODE, "ERROR_MESSAGE");
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Vatsal, thanks, but my example is a javascript server-side function under Google Apps Script. The Class HtmlOutput doesn't show a way to set an error return code.